# AVERAGEIFS returning #DIV/0

Tags: excel-formula

So I am creating a database which compares demographics of patients among other things. I am trying to use the AVERAGEIFS function to find the mean operative time for specific surgeries for only patients who have a BMI of above 40.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Data!P2:P255, Data!C2:C255, "*TYPE OF OPERATION*",Data!G2:G255, ",>40")
```

Column P contains the Operative time, C contains the type of operation and G contains the BMI of the patient. I keep getting a #DIV/0 error with this code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you get `#DIV/0` error nothing is matching your criteria.  Make sure your spelling is correct and there are no spaces or other non visible characters in the data.  Also `",<40"` is not correct.  It should be `"<40"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a comma in the last criteria ",>40". This should be ">40"

Also, if you fix the above and still get the same error, it is possible that none of the items in column C and/or G match your criteria.

See [Microsoft Documentation on AVERAGEIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)

[image]

Comment: That fixed the div/0 error however the math does not seem to add up. The average it is returning is not the real average of the table it is referencing.

Comment: So, when you filter the table down by column C and G to match the criteria in your AVERAGEIFS, you are saying the average you calculate manually of column P (filtered) does not match the result of the AVERAGEIFS function?

Comment: Correct.     =AVERAGEIFS(Data!P2:P255, Data!C2:C255, "*TYPE OF OPERATION*",Data!G2:G255, ">=40")  This is the code that i currently have.

Comment: I've edited my answer above to include a picture showing how I tested your formula. The highlighted items are the ones that match your criteria. Works perfectly. Are you sure your manual calculation is correct?  FYI -- the formula you put in your comments is different from the one in your original question.. you changed '>' to '>='